# How we can download file based on value selected inn dropdown in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

implementation in WordPress

In my website there is a WordPress contact form for downloading file. once you fill details you can download the file. now I want to change. now there is dropdown in contact form. depending upon the value selected in the dropdown, the related file should download

ex. dropdown having values: value1 and value2
and files are file1 and file2

whenever user select value1 in contact form then file1 should download

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you're going to just select a different success page with the download on based on the input value

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    if ( '4765' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Replace 4765 with your form ID 
      var whatDownload =  document.getElementById("selectID").value; // Replace selectID with your dropdownID
    if (whatDownload === "value1") { // Value 1 is whatever one of the values you want to check for
      // Redirect location for value1
      location = 'http://www.example.com/page1';
      } else if (whatDownload === "value2") { // Value 1 is whatever one of the values you want to check for
        // Redirect location for value2
        location = 'http://www.example.com/page2'; 
    }
  }
}, false )
```